# I am getting a syntax error while importing the zipfile module in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-zipfile

python command in script:

```
import zipfile
```

Output on screen

```
Chetans-MacBook-Pro:work chetankshetty$ python myprog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myprog.py", line 1, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/Users/chetankshetty/Documents/Work/zipfile.py", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Chetans-MacBook-Pro:work chetankshetty$
```

Comment: It's not myprog.py that has that bogus DOCTYPE line in it, it's zipfile.py - and the path indicates that it's something the user supplied, NOT the built-in zipfile module.  Get rid of that file, you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import the builtin `zipfile` module, but instead Python is trying to import a file in the current directory named zipfile.py. This is because of the [Python Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

From the docs:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
>     shell variable `PATH`).
> - the installation-dependent default.
>
> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The directory 
>   containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the
>   search path, ahead of the standard library path. **This means that
>   scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the
>   same name in the library directory.** This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

Python doesn't look in the directory where the builtin zipfile.py is because it finds work/zipfile.py first, which has invalid syntax and you probably don't want to be importing at all. The solution is to rename work/zipfile.py so Python can find the right file.